# Knockout.js if works only after load. Why?

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to show/hide html elements based on some properties using Knockout.js, but what I get is a blinking. Independently from the property value, all elements are shown at load and after some of them are getting hidden.

Here is my script:

```
  <li class="page-scroll" data-bind="if: !loggedIn()">
                    @Html.ActionLink(@ViewRes.SharedStrings.login, "User", "Home")
                </li>

  <li class="page-scroll" data-bind="if: loggedIn()">
                    <a href="#" data-bind="text: user().name, click: user().manage">
                    </a>
                </li>
```

The question is how to make knockout insted of adding all elements to DOM and after hidding them, not to add them at all. I tried even this script:

```
<li class="page-scroll" data-bind="if: false">                        
                    <a href="#" data-bind="click: user().manage" 
                       style=" background: url(/Content/img/vahagn.jpg) no-repeat center left; background-size: contain; border-radius: 30px; width: 60px; height: 60px; margin-left: 25px;">
                    </a>                                                                                       
                </li>
```

This element was shown in the process of loading too.
I tried this syntax too

```
 <!-- ko if: loggedIn()-->
my elements
 <!-- /ko -->
```

And the same happens in this case.

Any solutions?

Comment: knockout bindings obviously can't work if it hasn't been loaded yet. to get rid of the flicker, you'll have to manually hide the conditional elements and let knockout handle the visibility after it's loaded up

Comment: Thanks dperry for the answer, but any way I am getting blinking in this case too. Now all my elements are hidden during loading and after load some of them appear. In my case this element are menu buttons and blinking is really visible.

Comment: I would add a class to the elements that has `display: none` as the main attribute, then add a `visible` binding alongside the `if`. When the page comes up, the knockout-dependent items will be hidden and then switch on after knockout is loaded/ready. Should be no blinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class to all containers that have data-bound elements. Something like...

`hide-unbound`

That has a style of: `display: none`

Then, after `ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());` call something like...

`$(".hide-unbound").removeClass("hide-unbound");`